# js/cheerio get URL in class with dynamic name

Tags: javascript, cheerio

In js using Cheerio, for this block, where "*" is dynamic text (such as an ID #):

```
<a class="article-link*" href="https://www.somedomain.com">
```

How do I extract the URL?

Is it possible to use a wildcard to get information after part of an element's name? I tried:

```
$("[class = 'article-link']*") 
//fails probably because the string is terminated prematurely

$("*[class = 'article-link]*")
//malformed attribute (obviously, but thought I'd give it a whack)

$("*[class = 'article-link*']")
//fails (again, obviously)

$("*[class = 'article-link\*']")
//I was trying to escape the string, but I believe cheerio encapsulates the break character as part of the string because it's inside of [] - and idk if the wildcard can even be used this way
```

FYI - I can use a wildcard like this to get another element where information before a tag isn't the same (itemprop in this example) such as with different header tags coming before it:

```
var titleElem = $("*[itemprop = 'title']").get()
//gets [itemprop = 'title'] regardless of previous tag(s)
```

Comment: `$("[class^='article-link']")` - this is css btw.

Comment: I'm trying to get the URL in href. the class name isn't "article-link" it's "article-link*" where * is dynamic such as "article-link video12345"

Comment: I get that. Look at the css specs for `^=`.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why this didn't work for me previously, it is now. I must've fubared something in my logic previously. I was able to investigate the structure further and make sure I was selecting the right element before getting what you were saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I accessed it was this:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const $ = cheerio.load(html);

//article is the div directly above this link, list-wrapper the div before that, a is this element
const rows = $('.list-wrapper article a');

//.attr selects an elements attributes
url = $(rows).attr('href').trim();
```

I had other elements to grab from this class or I would've done this on a single line:

```
url = $('.list-wrapper article a').attr('href').trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

If the dynamic text is generated by Javascript then won't be able to access it via cheerio as cheerio is just a DOM parser.

If this is the case and you need to simulate browser action you could look into [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [Puppeteer](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/).

Comment: I'm not sure how its generated but it's part of the DOM

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer. If you're going to answer, provide a solution using the proposed headless browsers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `request` is that it can't execute javascript rendered data. Try using a headless browser instead. [Nightmare](http://www.nightmarejs.org/) is a great one.

```
npm install nightmare --save
```

You make a call using nightmare instance then pass the html code to your cheerio. Here is the sample:

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

nightmare
    .goto(url)

    //do something in the chain to go to your desired page.

   .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('body').outerHTML)

   .then(function (html) {
      cheerio.load(html);
      // do something in cheerio perhaps something like:

    let links = $("a[class^='article-link]").map(function(i, element) {

        return $(this).attr('href');
      }).toArray();

    console.log(links) // => [link1, link2, ...]

})
.catch(function (error) {
console.error('Error:', error);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is part of the DOM - they must generate the classname before writing the source instead of injecting it